# read files insert text into mysql

Tags: php, regex

myFolderi have thousands of image files that have keyword text for the name.  i am trying to read from the list of images and upload the text into a dB field.  the problem is that some of the text has utf8 characters like l’Été that show up like this ��t�

how can i read foreign characters so that the accents will insert into the dB field?
this is how im handling it now

```
function ListFiles($dir) {

if($dh = opendir($dir)) {

    $files = Array();
    $inner_files = Array();

    while($file = readdir($dh)) {
        if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
            if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);   
                if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
            } else {
                array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);//$dir = directory name
                //array_push($files, $dir);
            }
        }               
    }
    closedir($dh);
    return $files;
}
}

   foreach (ListFiles('../../myDirectory') as $key=>$file){
//$file = preg_replace( '@[^\0-\x80]@u',"", $file );
  echo $file ."<br />";
}
```

this is producing the same result

```
$str = "l’Été";
utf8_decode($str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: `utf8_decode()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Comment: your database and/or tables must be set for utf as well (collate and/or character set see: ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html ))

Comment: see also: http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Comment: utf8_encode fixed some but decorative quotes are still giving me issues

Answer (score 0):

This solution may work for you, it will loop through all files in a directoy and then recursivly through any directories found until it ends up with a massive array of files.

Ive added some points you may wish to change, eg either mutli or single dimension arrays ( all depend on if you may want to maintain the folder structure.

and also if you want the file extention to be saved when you save the file name to db.

**Code**

```
function recursive_search_dir($dir) {
  if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
     if (in_array($file,array(".","..")))
        continue; // We dont want to do anything with parent / current directory.

     if (is_dir($file)) {
        $result[] = recursive_search_dir($file); // Multi-dimension
           # OR
        array_merge($result,recursive_search_dir($file));// Single-dimension if you dont care about folder structure.
     } else {
        $result[] = utf8_decode($file); // full file name ( includes extention )
           # OR 
        $result[] = utf8_decode(filename($file,PATHINFO_FILENAME)); // if you only want to capture the name and not the extention.
     }
  }
  closedir($handle);
  }
  return $result;
}
$files = recursive_search_dir("."); // recursively searcht the current directory.
```